# how to maintain old value in Angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have created editable Grid in angular js.

issue that i m facing is if user click edit and change values and then cancel edit . it updates the scope that is default behavior as m using ng-model

but i wanted to preserver old state so in case if user tries to cancel i can set old values in Grid

**View**

```
<tr ng-repeat="course in courses">
                <td>
                    <span>{{course.id}}</span>
                </td>
                <td> 
                    <span ng-show="course.editMode == null || course.editMode == false">{{course.number}}</span>
                    <input class ="form-control"  ng-model="course.number" ng-show="course.editMode == true" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span ng-show="course.editMode == null || course.editMode == false">{{course.name}}</span>
                    <input class="form-control"  ng-model="course.name" ng-show="course.editMode == true" />
                </td> 
<div class="btn-group">
               <i ng-click="updateCourse(course)"></i>                              
        <i ng-click="cancelEditMode(course)"></i>
                        </div>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.courses = [];
 var oldvalue = '';
 $scope.toggleEditMode = function (course) {       
    course.editMode = true;
    oldvalue = course;
};
 $scope.cancelEditMode = function (course) {
    course.editMode = false;
    var index= $scope.courses.indexOf(course);
    $scope.courses[index] = oldvalue;              
};
```

i have tried to have a variable oldvalue and when user clicks edit i save existing value in oldvalue and then on canceledit i tries to set oldvalue.
but it didnt work, i always get new value in oldvalue.

can some one help me out wat i m doing wrong ?

Comment: You should fix the method name in your controller. It should be updateCourse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should create a copy of the object as the old value. You can use [angular.copy](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.copy) method for that. Otherwise you are operating on the same object and any updates to this object will change the old value too. Here's a [working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/A2IIHzw5qwOW7WRGmm8R?p=preview) in plunker.

You have a second error in cancelEditMode method because you are setting editMode property to false in the object you will replace. That's also fixed in the example.

Comment: Thanku very much issue is fixed by using angular.copy.

Answer (score 2):

That's because `course` is an object, and when you assign an object to some variable, that variable will hold only a reference to that object. So, when you change the original object (the `course`), the `oldvalue` reflects the change.

You need to make a copy of the original `course` object:

```js
...
oldValue = angular.copy(course);
...
```